# can you create / write / append a string to a file in a single line in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to do this?

```
v='some text'
w='my' + Time.new.strftime("%m-%d-%Y").to_s + '.txt'
File.write(w,v) # will create file if it doesn't exist and recreates everytime
```

without having to do File.open on an instance? Ie just a class method that will either append or create and write? Ideally a ruby 1.9.3 soln.

thx

**Edit 1**

here's what I tried based upon docs. I hadn't seen the rdoc but had seen some other examples. Again I'm just asking if possible to open a file in append mode via File.write? thx

```
irb(main):014:0> File.write('some-file.txt','here is some text',"a")
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
    from (irb):14:in `write'
    from (irb):14
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
irb(main):015:0>


irb(main):015:0> File.write('some-file.txt','here is some text',O_APPEND)
NameError: uninitialized constant O_APPEND
    from (irb):15
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
irb(main):016:0>
```

Comment: soln. thx. What a polite expression.

Comment: You can always do something in one line if you want.

Comment: @sawa not sure what soln bothers you, oh well

Comment: What is your question? File.write works and did you try?

Comment: I'm aware on new file, I'm trying to append. I've updated question; just looking for syntax

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Ruby has had [`IO::write`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-write) since 1.9.3.  Your edit shows you're passing the wrong args.  The first arg is a filename, the second the string to write, the third is an optional offset, and the fourth is a hash that can contain options to pass to the open.  Since you want to append, you'll need to pass the offset as the current size of the file to use this method:

```
File.write('some-file.txt', 'here is some text', File.size('some-file.txt'), mode: 'a')
```

Hoisting from the discussion thread:
**This method has concurrency issues for append because the calculation of the offset is inherently racy**.  This code will first find the size is X, open the file, seek to X and write.  If another process or thread writes to the end between the `File.size` and the seek/write inside `File::write`, we will no longer be appending and will be overwriting data.

If one opens the file using the 'a' mode and does not seek, one is guaranteed to write to the end from the POSIX semantics defined for [fopen(3) with `O_APPEND`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen); so I recommend this instead:

```
File.open('some-file.txt', 'a') { |f| f.write('here is some text') }
```

Comment: thx, this seems to do it. Not a big fan of that ruby api piece - just really ugly. Originally was looking at this for handling threading issues with block syntax that we have with code written like @ennuikiller . I doubt this is going to fix that though. thx again for answer, when I read that api docs first time I couldn't believe that was syntax.

Comment: @timpone Yeah, the use case for `IO.write` is nice for create or overwrite semantics, but awkward for append.  Might consider extendeding IO with `class IO; def self.append(fn,str,opts={}); IO.write(fn,str,File.size(fn),{mode: 'a'}.merge(opts)); end; end`

Comment: As I think on it again, this interface blows for append in a concurrent context because there's always a race between finding the file size and issuing the write. I think you're best off just opening the file in sync-append mode and writing.

Comment: isn't there a race condition on the block example like in @ennuikiller's example. One of the reasons we want to go with the single line example is better thread safety. Any info on what you think woudl be appreciated or more fleshing out of your most recent comment.

Comment: @timpone If you open the file in O_APPEND mode (ruby `'a'` mode) all writes will be at end of file ["Opening a file in append mode (a as the first character of mode) causes all subsequent write operations to this stream to occur at end-of-file, as if preceded by an fseek(stream,0,SEEK_END);"](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen). This relies on OS semantics and that ruby issues system writes on the open file and doesn't buffer internally.

Comment: Hi folks - new to ruby, but why is the File.size() needed if opening with 'a'?  Isn't `File.write('f.txt','message', mode: 'a')` sufficient?

Comment: @Beel because that isn't the argument signature of [`IO::write`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-write) -- which is why my earlier comment says this interface blows for append. A better way to this with correct append semantics, not subject to races is `File.open('f.txt','a') { |f| f.print 'message' }`

Comment: @dbenhur -- isn't the offset optional for File.write?  It seems to work without the offset in irb.

Comment: Two things:1) The original question was "create or writeP

Answer (score 12):

To make it clear as some comments are suggesting I tested this working:

`IO.write("/tmp/testfile", "gagaga\n", mode: 'a')`

That one appends to the file without need to calculate offset. Rubydoc is little misleading. Here's a bug about that:
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11638

Answer (score 4):

```
File.open('my' + Time.new.strftime("%m-%d-%Y").to_s + '.txt', 'w') { |file| file.write("some text") }
```

Comment: This is will write, but not append, to file. I believe OP was trying to append to a file. Create the file handle with 'a' when you want to append.

Answer (score 3):

MRI has that method already (I literally copied and pasted your code and it worked), but last time I checked, JRuby and Rubinius didn't. They might now, I don't feel like installing the latest versions to see.

http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/IO.write

Comment: thx for posting, I had seen this and updated question with edit 1. I tried file write with "a" but says it's looking for an int (which doens't appear to be consistent with rdoc) and then tried standard UNIX constant but doesn't like that either. Really, just looking to see if this syntax is possible. Not sure why all the downvotes

Comment: If you copy and pasted and it worked, your ruby is broken.  The problem with his call is that the third argument is supposed to be an integer offset, not a file mode.