# How to append a text to file succinctly

Tags: ruby

Instead of writing

```
File.open("foo.txt", "w"){|f| f.write("foo")}
```

We can write it

```
File.write("foo.txt", "foo")
```

Is there simpler way to write this one?

```
File.open("foo.txt", "a"){|f| f.write("foo")}
```

Comment: I can't see better way, but to do it without a block: `File.write("foo.txt", File.read("foo.txt")+"foo")`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a bit tricky. I'd like to go with simple way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can you create / write / append a string to a file in a single line in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865140/can-you-create-write-append-a-string-to-a-file-in-a-single-line-in-ruby)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes. It's poorly documented, but you can use:

```rb
File.write('foo.txt', 'some text', mode: 'a+')
```

Answer (score 28):

This has been answered in great depth already:

[can you create / write / append a string to a file in a single line in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865140/can-you-create-write-append-a-string-to-a-file-in-a-single-line-in-ruby)

```
File.write('some-file.txt', 'here is some text', File.size('some-file.txt'), mode: 'a')
```

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware of the optional offset argument. Good to know. Are you certain that `mode: 'a'` is required?  This is of course [IO::write](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-write).

Comment: Third argument can be omitted, will default to the end of the file.

Answer (score 18):

```
f = File.open('foo.txt', 'a')
f.write('foo')
f.close
```

Comment: I should have asked "simpler way" not "without block". It seems like there is no way like `File#write`. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @ironsand you are free to change your question and I'll remove the answer. It is just my opinion that this way is most readable, easy and doesn't require block.

Comment: @ironsand - While this might be a cleaner solution for you, it doesn't fully address the title of the question, and thus, in my opinion, making it unsuitable for an accepted answer.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov I see, I've changed the title. Thanks for heads up.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<<` instead of `.write`:

```
File.open("foo.txt", "a") { |f| f << "foo" }
```

Answer (score 3):

Although this was answered with multiple options, I have always felt that if Ruby has `File.write path, content`, it should also have `File.append path, content`, especially since the existing append syntax is not very pleasant.

So, whenever I need to append, I usually add this extension:

```rb
class File
  class << self
    def append(path, content)
      File.open(path, "a") { |f| f << content }
    end
  end
end

# Now it feels intuitive:

File.write "note.txt", "hello\n"
File.append "note.txt", "world\n"
```